# override internal state when props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

```
const MySelector = ({defaultOption, options})=>{
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(defaultOption);

const onChange=(e)=>{
   setSelectedOption(e.detail.selected);
};

 return (<Dropdown options={options}  selectedOption={selectedOption} onChange={onChange}  />)
};


const Page({selectedOption})=>{

   return (<MySelector selectedOption={selectedOption} options={[....]}  />); 

};
```

Myselector is a wrapper for a dropdown component. My page passes down the selected option to MySelector.

If the value of the selectedOption prop changes inside the Page, It doesn't change the value of the selectedOption inside mySelector because i'm using internal state. The only way to change the selectedOption is to trigger the onChange event but it doesn't change if the value changes in the parent component.
What's wrong with this structure?

Comment: you are passing `selectedOption` to `<MySelector ...` but consuming it as `defaultOption` inside the component?

Comment: IMO you should not use an internal state at all if you are going to pass in the `selectedOption`.  But if you want to do both, you need a `useEffect` hook which calls `setSelectedOption` when the value from props changes.

Comment: i like the idea of not using internal state at all. but how can i change the  value of selectedOption from the onChange event ?